# How can I create one connection using Transaction instead of two? Room with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

**Inside onCreateView method**

```
MainActivity.localDatabase.categoriesDao().getCategories().subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<CategoriesModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull List<CategoriesModel> categoriesModels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {

    }
});

MainActivity.localDatabase.subcategoriesDao().getSubcategories(1).subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<SubcategoriesModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull List<SubcategoriesModel> subcategoriesModels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {

    }
});
```

**CategoriesDao**

```
@Dao
public interface CategoriesDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES")
    Single<List<CategoriesModel>> getCategories();

    @Query("DELETE FROM CATEGORIES")
    void deleteCategories();

    @Insert
    void insertCategories(List<CategoriesModel> categoriesModelList);

}
```

**SubcategoriesDao**

```
@Dao
public interface SubcategoriesDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM SUBCATEGORIES WHERE category_id = :categoryId")
    Single<List<SubcategoriesModel>> getSubcategories(int categoryId);

    @Insert
    void insertSubcategories(List<SubcategoriesModel> subcategoriesModelList);

    @Query("DELETE FROM SUBCATEGORIES")
    void deleteSubcategories();

}
```

**LocalDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = {CategoriesModel.class, SubcategoriesModel.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class LocalDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract CategoriesDao categoriesDao();

    public abstract SubcategoriesDao subcategoriesDao();

}
```

I want to get the categories and subcategories that are stored in the room database, I did it such as the code above, But how can I avoid creating multiple connections?

Is it possible to get the categories and subcategories in one connection only instead of two?

What about Transactions or is there another way?

Please leave an example with your answer.

Comment: Since Both Tables is different, You will observe them in differently.

Comment: @Herry Is it not possible to make multiple queries in one transaction like MySQL?

Comment: In that case, You need to write JOIN query based on two table. For JOIN Query Both table must share one common column to be referenced.

Comment: @Herry Could you leave an example to explain that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply JOIN between your CATEGORIES table and SUBCATEGORIES.

Below is an exam of doing the JOIN with android ROOM.

Make sure you have CategoryID as ForeignKey in SUBCATEGORIES table.

You can try the following.

```
class CatSubCate{
    @Embedded
    var mCat: CategoriesModel? = null
    //Declare Column you need from the SUBCATEGORIES table
    var mSubCatId: String? = null
    var mCatId: String? = null
}
```

In Side

```
@Dao
public interface CategoriesDao {

@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES LEFT  JOIN (SELECT S.SubCatId AS mSubCatId, S.ID as mCatId FROM SUBCATEGORIES S GROUP BY S.ID) AS SUBCATEGORIES ON CATEGORIES.ID=SUBCATEGORIES.ID WHERE CATEGORIES.ID != :catId ")
    abstract fun getAllCategory(catId: String): Flowable<List<CatSubCate>>

}
```

For more info see this [android dev link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data)

Comment: It is better to explain that in Java not Kotlin

Comment: Unfortunately i work in kotlin only.. but you can consider same change in java

Comment: I did not study the `Kotlin` language yet, But `+1` for your effort. Why cannot use `@Transaction` with queries?

Comment: You can just add @Transaction annotation into your Dao class function.

Comment: Okay, I'll wait 6 days to see if there is anyone who will provide any solution, If no one leaves the solution then I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: I think you need to add exactly what you want as having two tables in android SQLite, Only way to fetch them into a Single observer will be to combine it using some king of JOIN, It can be LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN based on your actual requirement.

Comment: But in `MySQL`, I load `categories`, `subcategories`, `countries`, `cities`, `neighborhoods`, `streets`, and `currencies` in one connection using `MySQL Transaction`. Must get all data or cancel everything if any table fails to return the data. That is working perfectly on the `PHP` side.

Comment: After I get the data from the server I will save the data in the local database. But when the user opens the specific activity I want to load `categories`, `subcategories`, `countries`, `cities`, `neighborhoods`, `streets`, and `currencies` in one connection from the local database like what I did with `MySQL` but I don't know what is the best way to do that using `Room` library. Must get all data from the local database or cancel everything if any table fails to return the data.

Comment: I searched a lot in the internet for 9 days and I still searching, But can't find anything that is useful. I'm helpless 

Comment: Again, FYI, Don't compare MySQL features with SQLIte database. The best way would be to write the logic in the app side and fetch each database table entry and show then accordingly to your UI requirement.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I was busy. Could you explain more? Am I still need to create 7 connections?